# Fade in image when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, scroll

I am making a one page website and in the middle of the site i have a few images that i want to appear when the user is scrolling down. when the user is scrolling down, i want the image to fade in and stay at 100% opacity. Ive gone through loads of different scripts and none work. I have found a good code snipped but it still doesnt seem to be working. It just displays the image but with low opacity. 
Here is the code:

```
<script>
  var $win = $(window);
  var $img = $('.fadeInScroll'); // Change this to affect your desired element.
  $win.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();
    $img.each(function() {
      var $self = $(this);
      var prev = $self.offset();
      if (prev) {
        var pt = 0;
        pt = prev.top - $win.height();
        $self.css({
          opacity: (scrollTop - pt) / ($self.offset().top - pt)
        });
      } else {
        $self.css({
          opacity: 1
        });
      }
    });
  }).scroll();
</script>
<section id="about">
  <h2><center>Header</center></h2>
  <div class="fadeInScroll" display:="" opacity:="0" style="opacity: 0.1;"> <img src="/ap/wsf1.png" alt="trulycode-responsive" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-555"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I had started creating a library for it a while back. It has some of the major functionality you might be looking for, but it might be completely unsuitable based on your needs:
http://sukritchhabra.com/opacityChangeOnScroll/

Comment: Do you want a progressive fadeIn on scroll or do you want a fadeIn when the images comes in viewport ?

Comment: I see in the demo that when `fadeInScroll` scrolls into view when user scrolls down it fades in. so Is the problem that when the user scrolls up the div scrolls down and fades out. you don't want it to fade out?

Comment: @SukritChhabra I tried installing it but  the images wont appear anymore? i did this: <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sukritchhabra/opacityChangeOnScroll/master/opacityChangeOnScroll.js" type>

     <section id="about">
    
    <h2><center>Started From the Bottom</center></h2>
    
    
    <!-- 1 -->
    <img class="increase-on-scroll-down" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/656346837733912576/Mr2blC1B.png" alt>

 <!-- Abi First FB Message -->
 <br></br>
 <img class="increase-on-scroll-down" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/656346837733912576/Mr2blC1B.png" alt>

Comment: @smdsgn Hi, I would like a progressive scroll so as the person scrolls down the opacity goes up. there will be a few columms of images so i would like each one to appear as the user is scrolling

Comment: @jackblank thats correct, i dont want it to fade out

Comment: Ok so you just want your script blocks the fadeOut when the image is already fadeIn. Am I right ?

Comment: @smdsgn so once the image has faded in, i dont want it to fade back out. i just want them to fade in one by one as the user scrolls down

Comment: @WSx I'm unable to completely understand from the code in the comment what is happening. Would it be possible for you to create a fiddle or js bin and I can address the problem in reference to that?

Comment: @SukritChhabra on my site, the images wont display (website is: will.me.uk/ap/prin) but on Fiddle they do show up (apart from one image) take a look https://jsfiddle.net/u8tmnv9k/

Comment: @WSx, I just took a look at your site. The reason that is happening is that you have 2 classes which are causing this. One, `.hidden` which has a `display: none!important;` and `.wrapper img` which has `opacity: 0` by default.

Comment: @SukritChhabra So what do I do to solve this

Comment: @WSx remove those classes or properties?

Comment: @SukritChhabra what ones

Comment: @SukritChhabra I was just confirming what ones to delete? Im asking for help on one part. And yeah please address them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So if I correctly understand what you want, you can block your fade effect when your images are already fade in this way :

```js
var $win = $(window);

$win.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

    $('img.hidden').each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        var prev=$self.offset();
        if(prev){
            var pt=prev.top-$win.height();  
            var opacity = (scrollTop-pt) / ($self.offset().top-pt);
            $self.css({
                opacity: opacity
            });
            if(opacity >= 1) $self.removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else{
            $self.css({
                opacity: 1
            });
        }  
    });

}).scroll();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: orange;
  height: 2000px;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hidden" style="top: 400px;" src="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg"/>
  <img class="hidden" style="top: 1000px;" src="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg"/>
  <img class="hidden" style="top: 1600px;" src="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this code but everything just shows up blank. Take a look: will.me.uk/ap/prin (its the about section - its just blank)

Comment: I don't see the JS on your site. Also, you have already an `.hidden` class in your bootstrap.min.css who override the `display` attribute of your images. So change the hidden class on your images and in your script with something else.

Comment: hi I changed it but still no luck. theres nothing else that could conflict with the code is there?

Comment: Check your concole, you have an error. You have to put this script after jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the part where you have the inline style of `style="opacity: 0.1;` . Usually inline styles override the CSS you might have in the `style` tag. Look at this example I set the inline style to blue but the set it in the css to red the blue wins. maybe that is what is cause your opacity to stay the same.

```css
#element{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="element" style = "color:blue;">element</div>
```

That's one reason why it's better to add and remove classes for you styles

I see that your overriding the inline styles with other inline styles so the above may not have caused you problems anyways Here is your snippet working. I don't know exactly what you want. It fades in

```js
$(function(){
  var $win = $(window);
  var $img = $('.fadeInScroll'); // Change this to affect your desired element.

  $win.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

    $img.each(function () {
      var $self = $(this);
      var prev=$self.offset();
      if(prev){
        var pt=0;
        pt=prev.top-$win.height();    
        $self.css({
          opacity: (scrollTop-pt)/ ($self.offset().top-pt)
        });
      }
      else{
        $self.css({
          opacity: 1
        });
      }  
    });

  }).scroll();
})
```

```css
.top{
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(120, 30, 200, 0.3);
}
.fadeInScroll{
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top"></div>
<section id="about">

  <h2><center>Header</center></h2>

  <div class="fadeInScroll" display:="" opacity:="0" style="opacity: 0.1;">
    <img src="/ap/wsf1.png" alt="trulycode-responsive" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-555">
  </div>
  <div class="fadeInScroll" display:="" opacity:="0" style="opacity: 0.1;">
    <img src="/ap/wsf1.png" alt="trulycode-responsive" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-555">
  </div>
  <div class="fadeInScroll" display:="" opacity:="0" style="opacity: 0.1;">
    <img src="/ap/wsf1.png" alt="trulycode-responsive" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-555">
  </div>
  <div class="fadeInScroll" display:="" opacity:="0" style="opacity: 0.1;">
    <img src="/ap/wsf1.png" alt="trulycode-responsive" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-555">
  </div>
</section>
```